# How to use ES6 import/export feature without using any build system?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

I know some basics of JavaScript and new to ES6.

I just tried a simple ES6 feature import and export and it seems that it doesn't support browser. I searched and came to know that we must use any transpiler(babel) to convert the ES6 to ES5.

So, the import/export converted to CommonJs syntax. If it is like this then I can directly use CommonJs!?

1. If ES6 is ready then why latest browser doesn't support yet?
2. If Ihave to convert my ES6 to ES5 then why I have to code on ES6? I can
   direclty use ES5!

**Index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>    
</body>
</html>
```

**main.js**

```
import {square} from 'func';
console.log( square(6));
```

**func.js**

```
export function square(x) {
    return x * x;
}
```

**chrome error for Index.html**
[image: Chrome error - unexpected token import]

**chrome version**
[image: chrome verson - 59.0.3071.86]

**Update**

It's not duplicate of any answered questions, the referenced one was answered 5 years back. We are in JavaScript where every Monday we get new news ;)

Comment: [from the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import): `This feature is only beginning to be implemented in browsers natively at this time. It is implemented in many transpilers, such as the Traceur Compiler, Babel, Rollup or Webpack.`

Comment: @michał-perłakowski It's not duplicate, that question was answered 5 years back. We are in JavaScript where every month we get new things...

Comment: @M.Kumaran And when we haven't gotten this particular thing for 5 years, it's still a duplicate :-)